# PWA: How to access client's locally stored version of manifest.json

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

In an pwa project I'm shipping an user specific manifest.json (start_url has an indiviual parameter per user).

I am currently storing this parameter in a cookie when the app is launched / start_url is browsed. But if the app cache is cleared for some reason and the user browses a subsite, the parameter is lost.

So is it possible to read the value of start_url from the client's localy stored version of manifest.json using javascript?

Comment: Did you find a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch them using **Fetch API**. 
Path of `manifest.json` can be found where you imported in `html` file. 
Eg: `<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">`

```
fetch('/path/to/your/manifest.json')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
        console.log(json.start_url)
        // ... use them ...
    })
```

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem. I'm trying to access the local copy of manifest.json. Only this one contains the user specific parameter.

Comment: Yeah, But the local copy of your `manifest.json` was not present in browser by default. It will only be served by the server at start. So if you check with the path  manually you could get access for manifest.json